# Ubuntu 10.04 & Intel Hyperthreading

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, hyperthreading

Does Ubuntu 10.04 allow the use of hyperthreading with the new Intel i7 processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you install the SMP kernel.

see here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel